# enabling BINARY LOG on AWS RDS MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-5.7, binlog

**Context**

I am trying to enable BINARY LOGs on a MySQL RDS instance.

**Issue**

I used `CALL mysql.rds_set_configuration('binlog retention hours', 24)` without encountering an error.

And using `CALL mysql.rds_show_configuration` says "binlog retention hours" value is 24

But `SHOW BINARY LOGS` says "#1381 - You are not using binary logging"

Am I missing something ?

**Additional information :**

- using `SHOW GRANTS` results in `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP...`
- I tried rebooting the instance. It didn't work.
- automatic backups are enabled with a 1 day retention

**useful documents**

- [Using a Amazon-Managed MySQL-Compatible Database as a Source for AWS DMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html#CHAP_Source.MySQL.CustomerManaged)
- [AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_configuration.html)

Comment: what was the edit @RolandoMySQLDBA ?

Comment: The edit was just adding the `mysql` tag.

Answer (score 6):

Amazon will not allow the user to enable binlogs.

You have to enable automatic backups on the RDS Instance. The RDS framework will then enable binary logs for you. You cannot enable them manually. Please see this post in the AWS forums ([which states the reverse, setting backup retention to 0 disables binary logging](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=45258)).

The default backup retention is 7 days. I recommend setting

```
mysql> CALL mysql.rds_set_configuration('binlog retention hours', 168)
```

so as to match the back retention

Comment: Thank you. I tried the 168 hours retention, sadly it didn't work. Automatic backups were already enabled on the instance. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Please connect to MySQL and run `SHOW GRANTS();` and post the output in the question.

Comment: Done. Also I just found this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html#CHAP_Source.MySQL.Prerequisites
I will follow it and update the question with results

Comment: I am struggling with same issue. Enabled them in parameter group but nothings works

Answer (score 3):

I found this blog post that answered the question: https://blog.pythian.com/enabling-binary-logging-rds-read-replica/

Essentially, if you make sure your "Backup retention period" for your RDS instance is set to > 0 days, this will enable binary logs.