# How to disable binlog_format in AWS RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws

I created RDS on AWS and created MySQL v5.7 instance. I tried to find the `binlog_format` settings in parameter group but it seems to me that there are only three possible settings - like the screenshot below:

[image: https://www.ithome.com.tw/news/83545]

But the [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.MySQL.BinaryFormat.html) mentioned that there is a way to turn off the `binlog_format`. It said

> Set the binlog_format parameter to the binary logging format of your choice (ROW, STATEMENT, or MIXED). You can also use the value OFF to turn off binary logging.

But the `OFF` setting is just not on the screenshot above. So I am a bit confused.

Thanks everyone for help =)

Comment: Try a different version of MySQL? 5.7 is pretty out of date at this point.

Comment: It's called `log_bin` in MySQL.

Comment: @bbaird I am hooking MySQL v5.7 instance on a vendor application, running on EC2. So if the vendor app doesn't support v8+ I have no choice but to stick to MySQL v5.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to RDS, you may not see OFF as an option because doing automated backups requires binary logging.

Inside the [mysql.rds_set_configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_configuration.html) say this

> For RDS for MySQL, NULL means binary logs are not retained (0 hours).
>
> For Aurora MySQL, NULL means binary logs are cleaned up lazily. Aurora
> MySQL binary logs might remain in the system for a certain period,
> usually not longer than a day.

If you want to logically disable binary logging, you can set that manually like this

```
mysql> CALL mysql.rds_set_configuration('binlog retention hours', NULL);
```

NULL is the default retention hours. [See AWS Docs on this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_configuration.html). Also, I wrote about this 4 years ago (See my answer to [enabling BINARY LOG on AWS RDS MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216809/enabling-binary-log-on-aws-rds-mysql/216826#216826))

## CAPTAIN's LOG SUPPLEMENTAL

Personally, I have seen the OFF option when deploying Aurora. That's because Aurora has other redundancy mechanisms which do not need binary logging. You have the option list `ROW, STATEMENT, MIXED, OFF` where `OFF` is the default for Aurora.

Setting [binlog_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_format) to something other than `OFF` in the DB Parameter Group allows you to set up MySQL Replication from Aurora to external servers.

With RDS, OFF should never appear as an option for the reasons I just stated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thanks for pointing out the part that I misread.