# Need to keep each binlog files to 24 hrs

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws

We have a requirement that we need to keep each `binlog` files(like `mysql-bin-changelog.025249`, `mysql-bin-changelog.025250`, `mysql-bin-changelog.025251`....) of MYSQL RDS to minimum 24 hrs.

However, i see that `binlog` files are getting purged/deleted after 10-12 mins.

Below is the current setup in my RDS parameter group:

1. `binlog` retention hours is set to 24 hrs.
2. `max_binlog_size` is set to 134217728.
3. `binlog_expire_logs_seconds` is set to 2592000.

Also, my MYSQL RDS database is heavily used and has 400+ tables.

Please let me know which parameter i need to change, so that each bin log should be retained for 24 hrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon RDS does not allow you to manipulate binary logs the way you normally would on a given standalone server or  a VM.

You need to run two stored procedures

- [mysql.rds_show_configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_show_configuration.html)
- [mysql.rds_set_configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_configuration.html)

To emulate setting the expire_logs_days to 7 days, call this:

```
mysql> CALL mysql.rds_set_configuration('binlog retention hours', 168);
```

In your case, call this to set it to 1 day:

```
mysql> CALL mysql.rds_set_configuration('binlog retention hours',24);
```

Before and after setting it, run this to see the set value:

```
mysql> CALL mysql.rds_show_configuration;
```

I mentioned this before (`Sep 05, 2018` : [enabling BINARY LOG on AWS RDS MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216809/enabling-binary-log-on-aws-rds-mysql) )

Comment: Hi Ronaldo, Thanks for the response. binlog retention hours is set to 24 hrs(i have verified this thru show_configuration)

Comment: This is the issue - I have setup a DMS task with mysql rds as source and redshift as target however the task will run for couple of days and will fail with Error 1236 (Could not find first log file name in binary log index file) reading binlog in AWS DMS.). i have setup the binlog retention to 24 hrs. i see in the source mysql instance that the binlog files are getting purged in 10-15 mins and so i supect if by any chnace my dms task lags or get stuck(since i'm migrating(full load+cdc) 400+ tables in my task), then the task failes with the 1236 error. since my RDS instance is heavily used.

Comment: Error 1236 usually refers to replicating form an impossible possible (missing binlog or bad position number). You should raise binlog retention to more that 24hrs. I would raise it to 168 but I see you have max_binlog_size set to 128M. Could you increase max_binlog_size to 1G as well as reaise binlog retention to 168 (or at least 48 or 72) ???

Answer (score 2):

```
binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 86400

expire_log_days = 1
```

It won't hurt to change them both.  The latter is the "old" setting; the former (seconds) is new.  It is as if they want to change from one to the other, but are not yet forcing the change.

However, note that the purging won't happen exactly at that time; it will 'guarantee' that at least 24 hours is kept.

It looks like the current setting is for 3 days.

The `max_binlog_size = 128M` gives a clue of when it will think about purging.  If it takes a week to fill up that much, it won't purge nearly as often.  You could lower it (if Amazon lets you).  The size seems not to affect anything more than trivially.  (The old default was 1G; I saw no substantive change when that shifted.)

Comment: FWIW, binlog purging occurs when a new binlog file is opened.

Comment: Hi Bill/Rick- AWS doesnt allow me to change the value of "max_binlog_size(default is 128 M)" and apart from (binlog_expire_logs_seconds and bilog retention period), please let me know which parameter should i change to retain the binlog files.

Comment: @SumantKumar - Retain them forever?  And run out of disk space?  Why?

Comment: Hi Rick, I have setup a DMS task with mysql rds as source and redshift as target however the task will run for couple of days and will fail with Error 1236 (Could not find first log file name in binary log index file) reading binlog in AWS DMS.). i have setup the binlog retention to 24 hrs. i see in the source mysql instance that the binlog files are getting purged in 10-15 mins and so i supect if by any chnace my dms task lags or get stuck(since i'm migrating(full load+cdc) 400+ tables in my task), then the task failes with the 1236 error. since my RDS instance is heavily used. please suggest

Comment: I have to guess that RDS is doing something aside from what MySQL is doing.

Comment: Any workaround, please sir.

Comment: @SumantKumar - Sounds like Rolando has the answer in RDS.

Comment: HI Rick, yep asking him as well.